# Do HTML5 tags render as div in older browsers?

Tags: html

From what I've read (IE 6 - 8 aside), older browsers treat the following HTML5 tags as inline:

article, aside, nav, section, footer

If open the following html in a modern browser:

```
this is the <article>article</article> tag.
```

It will render like this:

```
this is the
article
tag
```

Why are HTML5 tags treated as block level tags in modern browsers but inline in older browsers?

I've also read somewhere that older browsers treat HTML5 tags as divs, which would mean block level.  However, I don't have a definitive answer for how older browsers treat these tags.

Comment: possible to duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891543/html5-not-rendering-header-tags-in-ie

Comment: Completely different.

Comment: [This](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/03/22/using-html5-semantic-elements-today/) may be useful.

Comment: @null: Great resource.  Looks like there is a mixture of ways, rather than single one, that older browsers will handle this scenario.

Comment: @null: Can you post as answer? I will accept.

Comment: @4thSpace Sure thing - posted

Answer (score 0):

The best resource I've found so far is [this article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/03/22/using-html5-semantic-elements-today/), from which the following snippets are taken:

> There are essentially three possible outcomes when HTML5 elements are
>   used in a page:
>
> 1. The tag is considered an error and is completely ignored. The DOM is
>      constructed as if the tag doesn’t exist.
> 2. The tag is considered an error and a DOM node is created as a
>      placeholder. The DOM is constructed as indicated by the code but the
>      tag has no styles applied (considered an inline element).
> 3. The tag is recognized as an HTML5 tag and a DOM node is created to
>      represent it. The DOM is constructed as indicated by the code and
>      the tag has appropriate styling applied (in many cases, as a block
>      element).
>
> As a concrete example, consider this code:
>
> ```
> <div class="outer">
>     <section>
>         <h1>title</h1>
>         <p>text</p>
>     </section>
> </div>
> ```
>
> Many browsers (such as Firefox 3.6 and Safari 4) will parse this as a
>   top-level `<div>` element with an unknown child element (`<section>`) that
>   is created in the DOM but treated as an inline element. The `<h1>` and
>   `<p>` elements are children of `<section>`. Because `<section>` is
>   represented in the DOM, it is possible to style the element. This is
>   case #2.
>
> Internet Explorer prior to 9 parses this as a top-level  but sees
>   `<section>` as an error. So `<section>` is ignored and then `<h1>` and `<p>`
>   are parsed, both becoming children of `<div>`. The closing `</section>` is
>   also seen as an error and skipped. The effective understanding of this
>   code in the browser is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> <div class="outer">
>     <h1>title</h1>
>     <p>text</p>
> </div>
> ```
>
> So older Internet Explorer browsers actually recover quite nicely from
>   unknown elements but creates a different DOM structure than other
>   browsers. Because there is no DOM representation of the unknown
>   element, you also cannot apply styles to . This is case #1.
>
> Of course, HTML5-capable browsers such as Internet Explorer 9, Firefox
>   4, and Safari 5 create the correct DOM structure and also apply the
>   correct default styles to that element as specified in HTML5.